# What binary poisons could work when ingested?

Tags: science-based, chemistry, low-fantasy, poisons

What are two non lethal substances that will combine to create a strong poison when ingested close together?

Hopefully my character would be able to drink one of the substances mixed in to a wine or whiskey that is shared out with a few people, but does not kill anyone (yet!).
Soon afterwards the character goes upstairs and takes some form of pill, which should have the other half of the poison in it. The pill could have been switched out weeks in advance, without detection. 
This combination kills them - but as multiple people drank the wine, and they have been taking the pill for days without being poisoned, it is difficult to piece together how they have been killed.

Preferably the two ingredients would be naturally occuring as it is a low-tech world, and without taste to help avoid detection, but I know that's very unlikely so no worries if it has some taste/smell! I'm sure I can find a way to play it off!

I *have* thought of sulphur tablets with Isopropyl aminoethylmethyl phosphonite in the wine, which creates a VX (a strong nerve agent), however I'm having trouble thinking of a way of the character being able to get hold of Isopropyl aminoethylmethyl phosphonite with only fantasy technology... Am also unsure of the quantaties needed etc.

Another option is an overdose of a certain chemical, with one half being in the wine and the other in the pills, but again I'm unsure of quantity and what would work best.

Edit: sorry forgot to say, the context is a murder mystery story in a fantasy world.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: Diet coke and Mentos come to mind. Each one alone is safe, but mix both in high enough quantities and you might cause internal damage quite spectacularly.

Comment: Do you want this to be deliberate or accidental?

Comment: Must it be a poison that's made? The wide world of drug-drug interactions can kill you in other ways, like suffocation (instead of a straight toxin).

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? I bet my yearly salary that there is such a thing...

Comment: @Renan hahaha great idea! got a mental imge of them whizzing round the room like a let-go balloon!

Comment: @Halfthawed deliberate!

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica yeah believe it or not it did cross my mind to do some googling first. not sure I could have come up with sulphur and Isopropyl aminoethylmethyl phosphonite off the top of my head. If you would like to do some research and find an answer to protect your yearly salary, be my guest.

Comment: If your character takes a pill every day, and you intend to switch it for a poison pill, why mess with the wine?  Make the pill the whole poison, whatever you like.  You have surreptitiously fed him a poison pill, like poisoners do.  Is that not adequate?

Comment: @Willk The point is that the pill could have been switched out days before to include half of the poison. As the character has been taking them for days beforehand with no poisoning, the pills aren't suspected. If he dies immediately after taking a pill in the bathroom, it's very easy to guess that whoever was seen leaving the bathroom earlier that day is the murderer.

Comment: @Mais I think L.Dutch get your yearly salary. What you're asking is commonly known as  Cross-reactivity. You can make simply test if you are not lactose intolerant and you eat meat treat yourself to a KFC and 2 hours later have a nice, cold glass of milk. Your stomach will inform you that you have been poisoned and will flush everything out. Lemons can block the enzymes making it unable to process dextromethorphan (like in cough syrup) and if not process it build up in bloodstream. And my favourite - loading a gun while brake dancing.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Thank you, but as I have already said, I understand the concept of binary poisons. What I am asking here is not if they exist, but specific examples that could be used in the way in which I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Mais then the question wouldn't qualify for worldbuidling.

Answer (score 4):

[Coprine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprine) is a mycotoxine, found in the mushroom [Coprinopsis atramentaria](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/coprinopsis_atramentaria.html), thus being obtainable in low tech setting, if you know what to look for. The substance is toxic when mixed with alcohol - how to make the unsuspecting victim drink enough alcohol in wine is left as an excercise for the reader...

Answer (score 3):

## Grapefruit juice and Codeine (etc)

There is a lovely [long list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapefruit%E2%80%93drug_interactions#Affected_drugs) of medication that should not be mixed with Grapefruit Juice.

One large subset of these are prodrugs, which are not active medication when consumed, but become active when digested. They are transformed by chemical reaction during digestion,

Grapefruit juice (and a number of other compounds) can substantially increase how much active medication is produced from the prodrug.
Thus triggering an overdose.

A common example is [Codeine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeine#Mechanism_of_action).
Codeine is a fairly common painkiller, hard to notice if you are taking it on its own.
it functions via being converted into morphine in the liver.
Grapefruit juice increases how much morphine is made.

So you dose someone up with a large (but sublethal) does of codiene (e.g. in the food).
Then serve grapefruit juice with the meal.
They get to die of an opiod overdose

Answer (score 0):

**Alcohol and Opiods**

Alcohol can react badly with other drugs and be potentially lethal. In the modern world it is dangerous to take alcohol with Codeine painkillers. These are available without prescription.

Opiods can be derived from plants like the poppy. The Victorians are famous for their opium dens. So modern technology is not needed to concentrate the important chemicals.

Answer (score 0):

[Monoamine oxidase inhibitors (MAOI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoamine_oxidase_inhibitor) and anything from the long list of substances they are known for their possibly lethal interactions. MAOI occur naturally and have nasty, potentially lethal interactions with a lot of other substances.

This is also a problem. If you put MAOI in the wine some guests may eat aged cheese and get the nasty symptom themselves. If you put it in the pill, the victim may experience the interactions on random days before the attack.

Answer (score -1):

You can build up tolerances to some poisons over the long term. Famously, this has been used for poisoning since the Renaissance era (IIRC) , so you can drink from the same bottle as your victim and survive.

Now go for the reverse: everyone else has built up immunity (because they grew up in an area which has lots of the relevant poison in the local water) but your victim, who came from elswhere did not.   Hence, one person dead, everyone else baffled as to what killed him.

Comment: The question specifically states that they want two individually safe substances that become poisonous when consumed together. This doesn't seem to address that.